# How to untrack file/folder in all branches in git?

Tags: git

I accidentally added a folder and a file to git index in the master branch. Then I created two branches and both have the folder and file in the index.

When working in branchA I noticed that and did `git rm --cached <file>` followed by `git commit -m "removed unwanted file"`, however when I try to switch to branchB I get the following error

`error: The following untracked tree files would be overwritten by checkout: <filename>. Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.`

Is there a way to untrack (remove from git index) a folder and/or file from all branches?

Comment: The error you mentioned is coming because the same file is also present in branchB and also modified & committed there. You can NOT untrack a file from git if it's committed in even one branch.

Comment: So ... how can I solve this prob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[git update-index](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) should do what you want

This will tell git you want to start ignoring the changes to the file
`git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file`

When you want to start keeping track again
`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file`

[Github Documentation: update-index](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)